# "Manage Products" in Admin Panel won't display and gives error

Tags: magento-1.9.2.0

Upgraded from Magento 1.8 to 1.9.2.

When going to Catalog->Manage Products, the page displays

"There has been an error processing your request"

Looking at log shows:

> a:5:{i:0;s:167:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146
>   Table 'xxxx_magento.warehouse' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT
>   `main_table`.* FROM `warehouse` AS `main_table`";i:1;s:7537:"#0
>   /chroot/home/sre/xxxxxx.net/html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

Have never used/setup warehouse and not aware of warehouse table. Ideas?

Comment: In previous (1.8) setup, it might have some works based on warehouse. If you have the backup of the files & database, go through it.

Comment: As far as I know there is no warehouse table in a stock magento 1.8 install. I presume this must have come from a module - maybe a stock management module.

Comment: I went through prod db and there are no warehouse tables. checking if any modules could be cause. thanks, and will report back

Comment: tecjam was right, it came from InnoExts module. Have to install that properly. Thx for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tecjam was right, it came from InnoExts module. Have to install that properly. Thx for help